# itunes not showing latest episodes in podcast

Tags: itunes, podcasts

iTunes is stuck showing old episodes that are no longer in this feed (2010-12-16 to 2010-12-22).  It does not show the latest episodes for me

http://www.catholic.com/audio/podcast/podcaster.php

The actual feed looks fine.  I've tried unsubscribing, deleting, adding the feed via Advanced->subscribe to podcast, through the store (which also shows the latest episodes), etc.  But for some reason it seems itunes has a cached version of the feed which it refuses to update.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does this article relate to your problem :

[How to Automatically Delete Podcasts Once You Have Listened To Them](http://www.ehow.com/how_4750480_podcasts-once-have-listened-them.html)

This can also be a problem with the feed itself - try to [validate your feed](http://feedvalidator.org/).

Comment: Thanks, but no- that's not my problem

Comment: I have transferred my comment to this answer. It is easy to have an error in the feed itself, so perhaps this is not *your* problem at all.

Comment: the feed is fine.  I've loaded the feed in itunes on another machine and it works fine.